# Boosting items by its own field values

Tags: solr, content-search, boosting

I'm using Sitecore 9.3 and Solr 8.2.1, I had Solr index-time boosting in my old search implementation, but after I upgraded to a new Solr version, it is deprecated now.

Imagine I have an item with field called **viewsCount**, what I want to achieve is boosting this item by the **viewsCount** value at the query-time, like this:

query.Where(b => b.Boost(b.viewsCount))

This is not applicable as I don't have the **viewsCount** value at the time of preparation the predicate, I had this value in html tags and it was used for boosting but in the old implementation for the time-index boosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Sitecore 9.3: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/search-result-boosting.html

You can store the viewsCount in an indexed field and sort by it. Or move away from LINQ and directly query Solr.